# Checking Prime number in 8086 Assembly

Tags: assembly, primes, x86-16, tasm

I am trying to check if a given number is prime or not in 8086 Assembly program using Turbo Assembler.
But maybe there is something wrong in my code, for some of the prime numbers(19,23,31,37) its showing its not a prime number. Rest of the prime numbers(2,3,5,7,11,17,29,41,...,71) are working well.

Here's the whole code:

```
DATA SEGMENT
NUM DB 37H
PR DB 0H
NPR DB 0H
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
START: ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
MOV AX, DATA
MOV DS, AX
MOV AL, NUM
MOV BL, 02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DX,0000H
MOV AH,00H

UP:DIV BL 
CMP AH,00H
JNE NEXT
INC BH
NEXT: CMP BH, 02H
JE NPRIME
INC BL
MOV AX, 0000H
MOV DX, 0000H
MOV AL, NUM
CMP BL, NUM
JBE UP

PRIME: 
INC PR
JMP EXIT

NPRIME: 
INC NPR

EXIT:
MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H

CODE ENDS
END START
```

Maybe the problem must be in this part?

```
UP:DIV BL 
CMP AH,00H
JNE NEXT
INC BH
NEXT: CMP BH, 02H
JE NPRIME
INC BL
MOV AX, 0000H
MOV DX, 0000H
MOV AL, NUM
CMP BL, NUM
JBE UP
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong, Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you single-step the inner loop for those problem cases in your debugger, what do you see?  What did it divide to get a zero remainder?  (You tagged this emu8086, which has a debugger built-in.  But you also tagged TASM, which is a separate assembler you might use in dosbox, so you'd need a separate debugger.)

Comment: @PeterCordes AX was 0023 and BX was 0005 at that time it had zero remainder, so BH got incremented and then I got remainder zero again after getting 0023 divided by 07. So is my method wrong? and is it possible to get correct results using the method I used (Sorry I m pretty new in this stuffs so I didn't knew what to tag) (I deleted my previous comment because it wasn't phrased well)

Comment: Why are you doing `CMP BH, 02H` / `JE NPRIME` at all?  The logic is non-obvious, and you didn't comment it.  After checking all divisors from 2 to `n-1` (or better just up to sqrt(n)), you know that `n` is prime.  One trick for detecting that you've passed `sqrt(n)` is by checking the quotient and divisor, as shown in my answer on [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/204902)

Comment: Also note that 23h (0x23) is *not* prime.  That's 35 (decimal), so it is divisible by 5 and 7.  The prime number `23` (decimal) is `0017h`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah I get it now!! Thanks buddy! maybe that's why I was getting wrong, I was thinking 23 as Dec 23 this whole time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your program and it works fine except that you seem to consider 0 and 1 prime numbers. That's not correct.

> A prime number is a number bigger than 1, that is only divisible by itself and by 1.

The quick fix is below:

```
...
MOV AL, NUM
cmp al, 2           <<<< Add this line
jb  NPRIME          <<<< Add this line
MOV BL, 02H
MOV BH,00H
MOV DX,0000H
MOV AH,00H

UP:DIV BL 
CMP AH,00H
JNE NEXT
INC BH
NEXT: CMP BH, 02H
JE NPRIME
INC BL
MOV AX, 0000H
MOV DX, 0000H
MOV AL, NUM
CMP BL, NUM
JBE UP

PRIME: 
INC PR
JMP EXIT

NPRIME: 
INC NPR

EXIT:
...
```

Not much of an answer if I would leave it at that! So allow me the following observations:

- Zeroing `DX` is a twice repeated, redundant operation
- You can load `BH` and `BL` in one operation
- Don't load the number at two different places
- The variables *PR* and *NPR* are mutually exclusive, so a single variable would be enough
- You don't need branching in order to increment the counter

The better fix is below:

```
  ...
  cmp  NUM, 2
  jb   NPRIME    ; 0 and 1 are no prime numbers
  mov  bx, 0002h ; BH=0 (counter), BL=2 (divisor)
UP:
  mov  al, NUM
  mov  ah, 0
  div  bl
  cmp  ah, 1     ; Only sets carry flag is remainder is 0
  adc  bh, 0     ; Conditional increment of counter
  cmp  bh, 2
  je   NPRIME
  inc  bl
  cmp  bl, NUM
  jbe  UP
PRIME: 
  inc  PR
NPRIME: 
EXIT:
...
```

Because your algorithm tries every divisor up to the number itself, even the above proposed changes will not make the program truly efficient.
I could add a version of the code that would be at least 10 times faster. In case you're interested, leave me a comment and perhaps I could add it in the weekend...

[**edit**]

### A fast check for primality

Trying to reduce the number of iterations and especially the number of divisions (`div` is a costly operation) is what we're after here:

- It is most efficient to split off the small numbers [0,3] first. This avoids extra tests in the loop.
- Next we split off the even numbers because, except for the number 2 (that we already have split off), no even number is prime.
- Therefore the loop only has to divide odd numbers. We can omit all the even divisors at once because dividing an odd number by an even number will never produce a zero remainder.
- We only need to test divisors up to the integer square root of the number. Luckily we don't need to calculate it. As long as the quotient from the division is still greater than the divisor we have not yet reached the integer square root.

```
; IN (dl) OUT (cx) MOD (ax,bl)
TestPrime:
  xor  cx, cx         ; CX=0 means NotPrime
  cmp  dl, 4
  jb   .Less4
  mov  bl, 1
  test dl, bl
  jz   .No            ; Number is EVEN, so not prime
  ; Remaining candidates {5,7,9,11,13,15,...}
.Loop:
  add  bl, 2          ; Division by {3,5,7,9,11,....}
  mov  al, dl
  mov  ah, 0          ; Will divide AX by BL
  div  bl
  test ah, ah         ; Remainder == 0 ?
  jz   .No            ; Yes, found an additional divisor, so not prime
  cmp  al, bl         ; Quotient > divisor ?
  ja   .Loop          ; Yes, continue up to isqrt(number)
.Yes:
  inc  cx             ; CX=1 means Prime
  ret
.Less4:
  cmp  dl, 2
  jae  .Yes           ; 2 and 3 are prime, 0 and 1 are not prime
.No:
  ret
```

### Prime numbers smaller than 256

Next table shows the number of `DIV` instructions that got executed and the time it took in nanoseconds. The middle columns are for the question's improved code, and the columns on the right are for today's optimized code. As numbers grow, so does the benefit.

| Number | IsPrime | DIV's | nsec | DIV's | nsec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 251 | 1 | 250 | 4163 | 8 | 495 |
| 241 | 1 | 240 | 4140 | 8 | 428 |
| 239 | 1 | 238 | 3967 | 7 | 285 |
| 233 | 1 | 232 | 3869 | 7 | 263 |
| 229 | 1 | 228 | 3809 | 7 | 285 |
| 227 | 1 | 226 | 3779 | 7 | 255 |
| 223 | 1 | 222 | 3697 | 7 | 263 |
| 211 | 1 | 210 | 3494 | 7 | 255 |
| 199 | 1 | 198 | 3298 | 7 | 263 |
| 197 | 1 | 196 | 3276 | 7 | 263 |
| 193 | 1 | 192 | 3298 | 7 | 263 |
| 191 | 1 | 190 | 3186 | 7 | 263 |
| 181 | 1 | 180 | 3020 | 6 | 315 |
| 179 | 1 | 178 | 2990 | 6 | 308 |
| 173 | 1 | 172 | 2900 | 6 | 285 |
| 167 | 1 | 166 | 2802 | 6 | 232 |
| 163 | 1 | 162 | 2742 | 6 | 232 |
| 157 | 1 | 156 | 2667 | 6 | 240 |
| 151 | 1 | 150 | 2637 | 6 | 240 |
| 149 | 1 | 148 | 2524 | 6 | 240 |
| 139 | 1 | 138 | 2382 | 6 | 240 |
| 137 | 1 | 136 | 2352 | 6 | 240 |
| 131 | 1 | 130 | 2254 | 5 | 285 |
| 127 | 1 | 126 | 2171 | 5 | 293 |
| 113 | 1 | 112 | 1946 | 5 | 255 |
| 109 | 1 | 108 | 1893 | 5 | 225 |
| 107 | 1 | 106 | 1871 | 5 | 225 |
| 103 | 1 | 102 | 1848 | 5 | 210 |
| 101 | 1 | 100 | 1750 | 5 | 225 |
| 97 | 1 | 96 | 1713 | 5 | 225 |
| 89 | 1 | 88 | 1555 | 4 | 270 |
| 83 | 1 | 82 | 1457 | 4 | 270 |
| 79 | 1 | 78 | 1465 | 4 | 240 |
| 73 | 1 | 72 | 1390 | 4 | 195 |
| 71 | 1 | 70 | 1284 | 4 | 202 |
| 67 | 1 | 66 | 1202 | 4 | 210 |
| 61 | 1 | 60 | 1209 | 4 | 195 |
| 59 | 1 | 58 | 1082 | 4 | 195 |
| 53 | 1 | 52 | 976 | 3 | 255 |
| 47 | 1 | 46 | 871 | 3 | 263 |
| 43 | 1 | 42 | 804 | 3 | 180 |
| 41 | 1 | 40 | 773 | 3 | 187 |
| 37 | 1 | 36 | 728 | 3 | 172 |
| 31 | 1 | 30 | 616 | 3 | 180 |
| 29 | 1 | 28 | 601 | 2 | 225 |
| 23 | 1 | 22 | 510 | 2 | 232 |
| 19 | 1 | 18 | 435 | 2 | 172 |
| 17 | 1 | 16 | 413 | 2 | 172 |
| 13 | 1 | 12 | 360 | 2 | 172 |
| 11 | 1 | 10 | 315 | 1 | 217 |
| 7 | 1 | 6 | 247 | 1 | 142 |
| 5 | 1 | 4 | 217 | 1 | 150 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 187 | 0 | 165 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 172 | 0 | 165 |

### Non prime numbers smaller than 256

Next table shows the number of `DIV` instructions that got executed and the time it took in nanoseconds. The middle columns are for the question's improved code, and the columns on the right are for today's optimized code. As numbers grow, so does the benefit.

| Number | IsPrime | DIV's | nsec | DIV's | nsec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 255 | 0 | 4 | 270 | 1 | 195 |
| 254 | 0 | 126 | 2261 | 0 | 202 |
| 253 | 0 | 22 | 518 | 5 | 345 |
| 252 | 0 | 2 | 202 | 0 | 180 |
| 250 | 0 | 4 | 285 | 0 | 142 |
| 249 | 0 | 82 | 1532 | 1 | 217 |
| 248 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 150 |
| 247 | 0 | 18 | 510 | 6 | 345 |
| 246 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 165 |
| 245 | 0 | 6 | 270 | 2 | 232 |
| 244 | 0 | 3 | 255 | 0 | 165 |
| 243 | 0 | 8 | 338 | 1 | 217 |
| 242 | 0 | 10 | 375 | 0 | 180 |
| 240 | 0 | 2 | 217 | 0 | 157 |
| 238 | 0 | 6 | 360 | 0 | 142 |
| 237 | 0 | 78 | 1442 | 1 | 187 |
| 236 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 142 |
| 235 | 0 | 46 | 916 | 2 | 232 |
| 234 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 157 |
| 232 | 0 | 3 | 180 | 0 | 157 |
| 231 | 0 | 6 | 270 | 1 | 187 |
| 230 | 0 | 4 | 247 | 0 | 142 |
| 228 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 150 |
| 226 | 0 | 112 | 2066 | 0 | 142 |
| 225 | 0 | 4 | 247 | 1 | 195 |
| 224 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 142 |
| 222 | 0 | 2 | 217 | 0 | 150 |
| 221 | 0 | 16 | 435 | 6 | 338 |
| 220 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 150 |
| 219 | 0 | 72 | 1352 | 1 | 225 |
| 218 | 0 | 108 | 1931 | 0 | 142 |
| 217 | 0 | 30 | 646 | 3 | 278 |
| 216 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 157 |
| 215 | 0 | 42 | 924 | 2 | 232 |
| 214 | 0 | 106 | 1893 | 0 | 165 |
| 213 | 0 | 70 | 1322 | 1 | 217 |
| 212 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 157 |
| 210 | 0 | 2 | 165 | 0 | 150 |
| 209 | 0 | 18 | 488 | 5 | 323 |
| 208 | 0 | 3 | 270 | 0 | 165 |
| 207 | 0 | 8 | 255 | 1 | 217 |
| 206 | 0 | 102 | 1893 | 0 | 165 |
| 205 | 0 | 40 | 811 | 2 | 202 |
| 204 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 165 |
| 203 | 0 | 28 | 631 | 3 | 278 |
| 202 | 0 | 100 | 1795 | 0 | 165 |
| 201 | 0 | 66 | 1254 | 1 | 217 |
| 200 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 165 |
| 198 | 0 | 2 | 165 | 0 | 150 |
| 196 | 0 | 3 | 232 | 0 | 142 |
| 195 | 0 | 4 | 240 | 1 | 187 |
| 194 | 0 | 96 | 1750 | 0 | 142 |
| 192 | 0 | 2 | 165 | 0 | 150 |
| 190 | 0 | 4 | 315 | 0 | 142 |
| 189 | 0 | 6 | 270 | 1 | 195 |
| 188 | 0 | 3 | 255 | 0 | 142 |
| 187 | 0 | 16 | 428 | 5 | 308 |
| 186 | 0 | 2 | 202 | 0 | 142 |
| 185 | 0 | 36 | 804 | 2 | 232 |
| 184 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 165 |
| 183 | 0 | 60 | 1142 | 1 | 225 |
| 182 | 0 | 6 | 270 | 0 | 157 |
| 180 | 0 | 2 | 165 | 0 | 157 |
| 178 | 0 | 88 | 1720 | 0 | 142 |
| 177 | 0 | 58 | 1134 | 1 | 187 |
| 176 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 150 |
| 175 | 0 | 6 | 270 | 2 | 232 |
| 174 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 180 |
| 172 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 157 |
| 171 | 0 | 8 | 300 | 1 | 187 |
| 170 | 0 | 4 | 247 | 0 | 150 |
| 169 | 0 | 168 | 2938 | 6 | 345 |
| 168 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 165 |
| 166 | 0 | 82 | 1540 | 0 | 142 |
| 165 | 0 | 4 | 240 | 1 | 240 |
| 164 | 0 | 3 | 232 | 0 | 150 |
| 162 | 0 | 2 | 157 | 0 | 150 |
| 161 | 0 | 22 | 510 | 3 | 278 |
| 160 | 0 | 3 | 247 | 0 | 157 |
| 159 | 0 | 52 | 1014 | 1 | 187 |
| 158 | 0 | 78 | 1442 | 0 | 142 |
| 156 | 0 | 2 | 165 | 0 | 142 |
| 155 | 0 | 30 | 646 | 2 | 263 |
| 154 | 0 | 6 | 270 | 0 | 150 |
| 153 | 0 | 8 | 375 | 1 | 187 |
| 152 | 0 | 3 | 247 | 0 | 157 |
| 150 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 150 |
| 148 | 0 | 3 | 270 | 0 | 150 |
| 147 | 0 | 6 | 270 | 1 | 202 |
| 146 | 0 | 72 | 1352 | 0 | 150 |
| 145 | 0 | 28 | 631 | 2 | 232 |
| 144 | 0 | 2 | 202 | 0 | 157 |
| 143 | 0 | 12 | 390 | 5 | 308 |
| 142 | 0 | 70 | 1375 | 0 | 165 |
| 141 | 0 | 46 | 916 | 1 | 225 |
| 140 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 165 |
| 138 | 0 | 2 | 165 | 0 | 195 |
| 136 | 0 | 3 | 232 | 0 | 150 |
| 135 | 0 | 4 | 247 | 1 | 195 |
| 134 | 0 | 66 | 1247 | 0 | 142 |
| 133 | 0 | 18 | 488 | 3 | 308 |
| 132 | 0 | 2 | 165 | 0 | 172 |
| 130 | 0 | 4 | 247 | 0 | 187 |
| 129 | 0 | 42 | 879 | 1 | 195 |
| 128 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 165 |
| 126 | 0 | 2 | 165 | 0 | 142 |
| 125 | 0 | 24 | 556 | 2 | 263 |
| 124 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 165 |
| 123 | 0 | 40 | 811 | 1 | 150 |
| 122 | 0 | 60 | 1209 | 0 | 142 |
| 121 | 0 | 120 | 2134 | 5 | 308 |
| 120 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 142 |
| 119 | 0 | 16 | 473 | 3 | 278 |
| 118 | 0 | 58 | 1127 | 0 | 165 |
| 117 | 0 | 8 | 300 | 1 | 202 |
| 116 | 0 | 3 | 247 | 0 | 172 |
| 115 | 0 | 22 | 556 | 2 | 270 |
| 114 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 165 |
| 112 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 150 |
| 111 | 0 | 36 | 758 | 1 | 187 |
| 110 | 0 | 4 | 240 | 0 | 157 |
| 108 | 0 | 2 | 165 | 0 | 150 |
| 106 | 0 | 52 | 1097 | 0 | 150 |
| 105 | 0 | 4 | 240 | 1 | 202 |
| 104 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 150 |
| 102 | 0 | 2 | 165 | 0 | 142 |
| 100 | 0 | 3 | 232 | 0 | 157 |
| 99 | 0 | 8 | 300 | 1 | 165 |
| 98 | 0 | 6 | 270 | 0 | 165 |
| 96 | 0 | 2 | 165 | 0 | 142 |
| 95 | 0 | 18 | 488 | 2 | 217 |
| 94 | 0 | 46 | 1036 | 0 | 150 |
| 93 | 0 | 30 | 646 | 1 | 195 |
| 92 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 157 |
| 91 | 0 | 12 | 390 | 3 | 308 |
| 90 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 180 |
| 88 | 0 | 3 | 232 | 0 | 187 |
| 87 | 0 | 28 | 631 | 1 | 187 |
| 86 | 0 | 42 | 871 | 0 | 142 |
| 85 | 0 | 16 | 428 | 2 | 232 |
| 84 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 180 |
| 82 | 0 | 40 | 819 | 0 | 157 |
| 81 | 0 | 8 | 293 | 1 | 202 |
| 80 | 0 | 3 | 232 | 0 | 142 |
| 78 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 157 |
| 77 | 0 | 10 | 323 | 3 | 278 |
| 76 | 0 | 3 | 232 | 0 | 142 |
| 75 | 0 | 4 | 240 | 1 | 150 |
| 74 | 0 | 36 | 758 | 0 | 150 |
| 72 | 0 | 2 | 165 | 0 | 142 |
| 70 | 0 | 4 | 315 | 0 | 142 |
| 69 | 0 | 22 | 518 | 1 | 187 |
| 68 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 142 |
| 66 | 0 | 2 | 165 | 0 | 142 |
| 65 | 0 | 12 | 390 | 2 | 232 |
| 64 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 142 |
| 63 | 0 | 6 | 270 | 1 | 150 |
| 62 | 0 | 30 | 646 | 0 | 150 |
| 60 | 0 | 2 | 165 | 0 | 150 |
| 58 | 0 | 28 | 751 | 0 | 142 |
| 57 | 0 | 18 | 488 | 1 | 195 |
| 56 | 0 | 3 | 270 | 0 | 165 |
| 55 | 0 | 10 | 368 | 2 | 232 |
| 54 | 0 | 2 | 202 | 0 | 180 |
| 52 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 157 |
| 51 | 0 | 16 | 428 | 1 | 195 |
| 50 | 0 | 4 | 240 | 0 | 142 |
| 49 | 0 | 48 | 1044 | 3 | 270 |
| 48 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 165 |
| 46 | 0 | 22 | 593 | 0 | 157 |
| 45 | 0 | 4 | 240 | 1 | 187 |
| 44 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 165 |
| 42 | 0 | 2 | 202 | 0 | 142 |
| 40 | 0 | 3 | 270 | 0 | 142 |
| 39 | 0 | 12 | 398 | 1 | 187 |
| 38 | 0 | 18 | 488 | 0 | 142 |
| 36 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 150 |
| 35 | 0 | 6 | 270 | 2 | 247 |
| 34 | 0 | 16 | 420 | 0 | 150 |
| 33 | 0 | 10 | 323 | 1 | 187 |
| 32 | 0 | 3 | 232 | 0 | 142 |
| 30 | 0 | 2 | 202 | 0 | 150 |
| 28 | 0 | 3 | 263 | 0 | 165 |
| 27 | 0 | 8 | 293 | 1 | 195 |
| 26 | 0 | 12 | 465 | 0 | 142 |
| 25 | 0 | 24 | 563 | 2 | 232 |
| 24 | 0 | 2 | 210 | 0 | 142 |
| 22 | 0 | 10 | 323 | 0 | 150 |
| 21 | 0 | 6 | 270 | 1 | 202 |
| 20 | 0 | 3 | 232 | 0 | 150 |
| 18 | 0 | 2 | 225 | 0 | 150 |
| 16 | 0 | 3 | 232 | 0 | 157 |
| 15 | 0 | 4 | 232 | 1 | 187 |
| 14 | 0 | 6 | 263 | 0 | 142 |
| 12 | 0 | 2 | 217 | 0 | 157 |
| 10 | 0 | 4 | 315 | 0 | 157 |
| 9 | 0 | 8 | 308 | 1 | 217 |
| 8 | 0 | 3 | 247 | 0 | 150 |
| 6 | 0 | 2 | 217 | 0 | 142 |
| 4 | 0 | 3 | 240 | 0 | 165 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 165 | 0 | 187 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 157 | 0 | 187 |

Comment: There were lot of redundancy in my code but I fixed it from your observations, Thank You very much for your help! (And for now I could only think of this algorithm so it might not be very efficient)

Comment: @TanayChawda The optimized code that I promised has been added to the answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Your CPU is a Pentium-M or something, IIRC.  It should avoid a partial-register stall to do `xor ax,ax` / `mov al, dl` instead of writing AH by itself, assuming `div r/m8` reads AX as a whole, not two 8-bit halves.  On P6-family before Core 2, a partial register stall costs at least 7 cycles in the front-end.  (I wonder how much of that can overlap with the back-end div throughput...)  Even better would be `xor eax,eax` / `mov al,dl` or `movzx ax, dl` (or better EAX), but Pentium-M is old enough that it might still handle 16-bit zeroing idioms.

Comment: Avoiding writing AH by itself is [also better for modern Intel (Sandybridge-family)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to).  There you'll have a false dependency for writing AL or AX (unavoidable unless you write the full EAX), but you won't have any extra partial-register merging delays if you never write to AH except as part of AX/EAX.  (Of course this is for running natively, not running emu8086 interpreting this code.)

Comment: Avoiding a false dependency would be quite nice on newer CPUs where `div` is pipelined with throughput significant better than latency.  AMD and other CPUs that don't rename partial registers at all treat partial-register write as RMW operations on the full register, so the old value of EAX is an input to `mov ah,0`.