# Program keeps saying "Not a prime number" for any number I enter

Tags: assembly, primes, x86-16, emu8086

So this is my first time writing a post here. I'm very new to the assembly language and started the learning journey with emu8086.

Recently I wrote a program that detects if the number entered is either positive or negative and determines whether it's a prime number or not. I made it the first part (detecting positive or negative numbers, using array), but for some reason it keeps saying "Not a prime number" for any numbers I enter.
I tried to get it to copy the number stored in the array and bring it over to the prime/not prime section of the program but to not avail.
Anyone know what exactly the problem is? I'm pretty lost right now.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
.MODEL  SMALL 
.STACK 100H
.DATA  
ARRAY DB DUP('$')

          NUM       DB      ?
          MSG1      DB      0AH,0DH,'ENTER YOUR DESIRED NUMBER:','$'
          MSG2      DB      0AH,0DH,'NOT A PRIME NUMBER','$'
          MSG3      DB      0AH,0DH,'A PRIME NUMBER','$'  
          POSI      DB      0AH,0DH,'A POSITIVE NUMBER','$'
          NEGA      DB      0AH,0DH,'A NEGATIVE NUMBER','$'

.CODE
MAIN    PROC

            MOV AX,@DATA
            MOV DS,AX
            MOV SI, OFFSET ARRAY

            LEA DX,MSG1
            MOV AH,9
            
            INT 21H
    
            MOV AH,1
            INT 21H
            
            CMP AL,13
            JE CHECK
            MOV [SI],AL  
            INC SI
            JMP L1

    L1:
    MOV AH,1
    INT 21H
    CMP AL,13
    JE CHECK
    MOV [SI],AL  
    INC SI
    JMP L1 
    
    CHECK:
    CMP ARRAY, '-' ;IF ARRAY CONTAINS - SIGN THEN THE NUMBER IS NEGATIVE
    JE L2
    
    MOV DX, OFFSET POSI
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H  
    
    JMP EXIT1

    L2:
    MOV DX, OFFSET NEGA
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H

    EXIT1:
    mov al, [NUM]
mov bl, al
sub al, 2
mov cl, al ; counter value

; original input

mov dl, 2
l3:
mov ax, bx
div dl
cmp ah, 0h
jz pnot
inc dl

loop  l3

mov ah, 9h
  lea dx, msg3
  int 21h
  jmp end
  
pnot:
  mov ah, 9h
  lea dx, msg2
  int 21h

END:
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
    
    MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: A good point to start learning how to **debug** with a debugger. Also you might want to write more calculating code first in a high level programming language, so you know the processing logic is right.

Comment: What's the high half of AX (dividend) when you run `div`?  You don't write BH or the full BX anywhere in your program, only BL, so the high half could be non-zero garbage, leading to a #DE exception if the quotient doesn't fit in 8 bits.  But use the debugger built-in to emu8086 to single-step your code and watch register values change, to see how execution gets to the "not a prime" message.

Comment: You can start debugging, by examining your data.  Check to see how much storage each label has -- get to know the layout of your data before starting single step debugging.  Examine the storage using the debugger before running any of its code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your new code that wants to deal with prime numbers to an already broken program!
In the `.DATA` section you have written:

> ```
> ARRAY DB DUP('$')
> NUM       DB      ?
> ```

It's beyond me how this gets through emu8086's parser seeing the absence of a count for the `DUP` operator. Probably both *ARRAY* and *NUM* refer to the same memory address where there is room reserved for just 1 byte.
Your "positive/negative" program inputs a multi-digit number with an optional minus in front of it, and that program seemed to work fine since you were only comparing a single byte to "-" and having the first message been overwritten didn't show itself.

The program that you write today is not dealing with a multi-digit number, but rather just processes the first digit that was inputted (hopefully it was indeed a digit and not a minus character or anything else).
Because of the error with the definition of the *ARRAY*, the `mov al, [NUM]` instruction can retrieve that first digit **but this digit is still in its character form**. It is an ASCII code in the range 48 to 57. You need to subtract 48 before you use it in your calculations.
The calculation is also dangerously wrong because you divide AX by DL without knowing what is in AH, and because you use the `loop` instruction that depends on the CX register without knowing what is in CH.

Next code shows the corrections. I made no attempt at optimizing because that would hardly pay in this case... Anyway there's always [Checking Prime number in 8086 Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71832532/checking-prime-number-in-8086-assembly/71877290) for those interested in an optimized version of the code.

```
          ...

.DATA  
ARRAY     DB      16 DUP(0)
NUM       DB      0
MSG1      DB      0AH,0DH,'ENTER YOUR DESIRED NUMBER:','$'

          ...

          If you find that the first byte at ARRAY is '-'
          then better not start the prime test

          ...

EXIT1:  mov     al, [ARRAY]         ; ["0","9"]
        sub     al, 48              ; [0,9]
        mov     bl, al              ;
        mov     bh, 0               ; AL -> BX (original number)
        mov     cl, al
        mov     ch, 0
        sub     cx, 2               ; AL-2 -> CX (loop count)
        jbe     YES                 ; Consider [0,2] prime for simplicity!
        mov     dl, 2               ; Processing [3,9] with CX=[1,7] so LOOP doesn't fail
l3:     mov     ax, bx
        div     dl
        cmp     ah, 0
        je      NO
        inc     dl
        loop    l3

YES:    mov     ah, 9h
        lea     dx, msg3
        int     21h
        jmp     end
  
NO:     mov     ah, 9h
        lea     dx, msg2
        int     21h

END:    mov     ax, 4C00h
        int     21h

        ...
```