# MASM Printing prime numbers

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, calling-convention

Hi so I'm having problem with my Assembly project. I am supposed to print out x prime numbers in order. But I cannot use the fuction USES. When I tried to remove it, I got an infinite loop. Can someone please help me, thank you

```
isPrime PROC USES ECX EBX
; Checks whether a number is prime or not. If given number is prime, returns
; boolean value 1. Otherwise, returns 0.
; receives: A number in EAX
; returns: boolean value(0 or 1) in EAX
; preconditions: eax is in [1..200]
; registers changed: eax, ebx, ecx, edx
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        mov ecx,eax                         ; copy the number p into ECX
        mov esi, 2                          ; i=2
  startLoop:
        cmp esi,ecx                         
        jge PrimeNum                        ; if i>=p, p is prime and goto PrimeNum
        mov edx,0
        mov eax,ecx
        div esi                             ; calculate p/i. EAX=p/i and EDX=p%i
        cmp edx, 0                          
        je  NotPrime                        ; if remainder = 0, p is not prime
        inc esi                             ; otherwise, continue search
        jmp startLoop
PrimeNum:   
    mov eax, TRUE                           ; if p is prime , return true
    ret
NotPrime:
    mov eax, FALSE                          ; if p is not prime, return true
    ret
isPrime ENDP
```

When I removed the USES part

```
mov ecx,eax                         ; copy the number p into ECX
        mov try2, 2                         ; i=2
  startLoop:
        cmp try2,ecx                            
        jge PrimeNum                        ; if i>=p, p is prime and goto PrimeNum
        mov edx,0
        mov eax,ecx
        div try2                                ; calculate p/i. EAX=p/i and EDX=p%i
        cmp edx, 0                          
        je  NotPrime                        ; if remainder = 0, p is not prime
        inc try2                                ; otherwise, continue search
        jmp startLoop
PrimeNum:   
    mov eax, TRUE                           ; if p is prime , return true
    
    
    ret
NotPrime:
    mov eax, FALSE                          ; if p is not prime, return true
    ret
```

Comment: Have you tried push & pop instead?  push each at the beginning and pop them at the end (in the reverse order pushed).

Comment: @ErikEidt I have tried push and pop but I don't think I know where to place them correctly, it stopped the program after printing 2 values

Comment: Push immediately upon function entry and pop as the last before ret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> isPrime PROC USES ECX EBX
> ```

Although this claims to be using EBX, the code actually uses ESI and doesn't even touch EBX.

If you don't want to rely on `USES`, you'll need to preserve the registers that you want to keep or that need preserving. Because your code has multiple `ret` instructions, you also need multiple restoration sequences:

```
isPrime PROC
    push ecx         ;
    push edx         ; Preserves ECX EDX ESI
    push esi         ;
    mov  ecx, eax    ; copy the number p into ECX
    mov  esi, 2      ; i=2
  startLoop:
    cmp  esi, ecx                          
    jge  PrimeNum    ; if i>=p, p is prime and goto PrimeNum
    mov  edx, 0
    mov  eax, ecx
    div  esi         ; calculate p/i. EAX=p/i and EDX=p%i
    cmp  edx, 0                          
    je   NotPrime    ; if remainder = 0, p is not prime
    inc  esi         ; otherwise, continue search
    jmp  startLoop
  PrimeNum:   
    mov  eax, TRUE   ; if p is prime , return true
    pop  esi         ;
    pop  edx         ; Restores ESI EDX ECX
    pop  ecx         ;
    ret
  NotPrime:
    mov  eax, FALSE  ; if p is not prime, return true
    pop  esi         ;
    pop  edx         ; Restores ESI EDX ECX
    pop  ecx         ;
    ret
isPrime ENDP
```

It would be easy to avoid this double `ret`:

```
isPrime PROC
    push ecx         ;
    push edx         ; Preserves ECX EDX ESI
    push esi         ;
    mov  ecx, eax    ; copy the number p into ECX
    mov  esi, 2      ; i=2
  startLoop:
    mov  eax, TRUE   ; if p is prime , return true
    cmp  esi, ecx                          
    jge  PrimeNum    ; if i>=p, p is prime and goto PrimeNum
    mov  edx, 0
    mov  eax, ecx
    div  esi         ; calculate p/i. EAX=p/i and EDX=p%i
    cmp  edx, 0                          
    je   NotPrime    ; if remainder = 0, p is not prime
    inc  esi         ; otherwise, continue search
    jmp  startLoop
  NotPrime:
    mov  eax, FALSE  ; if p is not prime, return true
  PrimeNum:   
    pop  esi         ;
    pop  edx         ; Restores ESI EDX ECX
    pop  ecx         ;
    ret
isPrime ENDP
```

This code is still not optimal for checking primality. You can find more ideas about a fast check for primality in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71832532/checking-prime-number-in-8086-assembly/71877290?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C37.8705#71877290)

Comment: Thank you I will try to look into it more!